# Middleware Not Getting Called by `alice`

Tags: web-applications, go, middleware

Why only `ServeHTTP` method of `H1` is getting called here and those of `H2` and `H3` seem to be ignored?

[alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice) seems to be a nice middleware chaining and here I've tried to use it with [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter), but only the outer/last middleware is getting called:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "github.com/justinas/alice"
    "net/http"

    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("started ", time.Now())

    c := alice.New(S1, S2, S3).Then(nil)

    router := httprouter.New()
    router.Handler("GET", "/app", c)

    http.ListenAndServe(":27007", router)
}

func S1(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    var x H1
    return &x
}

func S2(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    var x H2
    return &x
}

func S3(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    var x H3
    return &x
}

type H1 struct{}

func (h *H1) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println("H1", time.Now())
}

type H2 struct{}

func (h *H2) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println("H2")
}

type H3 struct{}

func (h *H3) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println("H3")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your middleware handlers need to call the next handler when ready. Untested example:

```
func S1(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return &H1{next: h}
}

type H1 struct{
    next http.Handler
}

func (h *H1) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println("H1", time.Now())
    h.next.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

Or:

```
func S1(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        log.Println("H1", time.Now())
        next(rw, req)
    })
}
```

Look at http://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=37638:37688#L1280 for another example of middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Each middleware is passed an `http.Handler` structure that you execute. This allows each middleware to not know the order of handlers, and they only concern themselves with simply executing the next one in the chain. Order is defined when you initiate Alice. See:

- http://adampresley.com/2015/02/08/using-a-middleware-in-your-go-web-applications.html
- https://justinas.org/alice-painless-middleware-chaining-for-go/